# Delete record on database through PHP button

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I'm trying to add a delete button on a table row, once the user clicks it, I want it to delete the record on the mysql database and therefore, not show on the table. My problem is when I click the delete button, I get a connection error! message, here's my php code:

```
<?php

        $id = $_GET['id'];


        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db') or die('Connection error!');



        $query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = '$id'";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Database error!');
        \header('location:datapull.php');

    ?>
```

thanks for any help in advance...

Comment: Get the real error `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` instead of `or die('Connection error!')` same thing for your query. Plus, is `table` your actual table name? I had to ask. Plus, get rid of the \ in `\header`

Comment: failure to connect, been there bro

Comment: Also at a minimum cast $id to an int. It's best to use prepared statements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1

Comment: Just so you know your script is vulnerable to SQL injection, anyone could pass `?id=' or '1'='1` to your script and delete every single row in that table. Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to sanitize your input.

Comment: ok I switched it, now I get a blank page. My table name is not table, I just put it there for reference. i also got rid of the backslash. But all I get is a blank page

Comment: Blank page means syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. You should also show the rest of your code. You're not showing us everything. As well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Plus, what @AlphaDelta said to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. You may be trying to enter something that MySQL doesn't agree with. `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()` will tell you that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats my whole php code, are you refering to where the begin button is located?

Comment: Yes. If that is part of your PHP and in the same file. By the way, are you running this from your own computer or hosted site? If localhost; are you accessing via `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got these errors: 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home2/doctorc0/public_html/consultas/delete.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home2/doctorc0/public_html/consultas/delete.php on line 9

Comment: @Fred-ii- hosted site

Comment: username or password or db is incorrect

Comment: `mysqli_error()` requires DB connection passed to it `mysqli_error($dbc)`

Comment: what should I do? im sorry, I dont know much... @Fred-ii-

Comment: `$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($dbc));` and `mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));`

Comment: untill the connection is fixed you cant parse it on to the other functions

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's telling me I have denied access:  Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home2/doctorc0/public_html/consultas/delete.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home2/doctorc0/public_html/consultas/delete.php on line 9
Error

Comment: It's a permissions issue then. Check all credentials and that you chose the right database. Make sure you have `delete` rights also. You may not have that right to do it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Im so sorry, there was a letter missing, its going back to the datapull.php but its not deleting the row, I still see the info on it...

Comment: I'd like to help further, but I really have to go to bed now; and my back's out. If nobody provides a solution, I'll come back to the question tomorrow. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Step1. Over check: localhost,user,pass and db

Step2: Check privilege of user on your database.

If it does not work, I am over-sure that there is problem in your server. At that case contact with customer support of your server.

Comment: @Dagon one of those *foot in the door* answers; just like the other one.

Comment: @dagon Im sorry if didnt respond, thanks for your help, Im still having issues, apparently the php code goes through because it redirects to the page but it doesnt delete the record on the database

Comment: Actually, I did not read all comments. I only read last comment " 
thanks a lot you guys, if anybody could help me further, it would be much appreciated". And I know this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Dagon I got your back ^

Answer (score -1):

Double check your database username, password and database name.

Try this code and reply me with what you are getting.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];    
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db') or die('Connection error!');
//Variables inside single quotes wont work. Change to this
$query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = '".$id."'";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Database error!');
// Check how many rows is affected. If it is returns 0 it is not working. Else it will return how many rows is deleted.
printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)); 
exit;
```

Comment: did you got `Records deleted:` with count of rows?

Comment: no, the page just loads the same. Nothing else to show

Comment: I updated the code. Check with that and use `exit`. So you can also able to view what is happening.

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it just tries to refresh the page and it stays the same. it won't print anything

Comment: I think you used the `header` before `exit` statement. Please comment the `header` statement or use `exit` before header and then check. `header` causes reloading. `exit` will terminate the execution of the script next to `exit` statement. So if you use `exit` before the `header` it wont let it to load the page.

Comment: Header has been commented but still does the same, I will link a pastebin of the code

Comment: I tried with my db. I'm getting this `Records deleted: 1`. So give the entire code which you are working with.

Comment: the php where the table is posted: [link](http://pastebin.com/5rUBUh5K) you have the delete.php

Comment: run the `delete.php` (which contains the delete code) with the id like `delete.php?id=10`. Instead of `10` use whatever id which you want to delete and then check whether you are getting `Records deleted:` and reply back.

Comment: perfect! it deleted one once I put an Id number, but how do I make it delete it without having to put it in?

Comment: I had to add an id number on the link and thats how it deleted it

Comment: You are using `$id = $_GET['id']` in your code. So, `$_GET['id']` will hold the value of attribute `id` in the `get method(appended in url)`. Check more about [get](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). If you think it solves the issue then accept the answer.